# VLC playlist parameters with spaces

Tags: excel, vba, vlc

on my excel sheet the user can choose some video clips and arrange in different order to play as a vlc playlist. Unfortunately it can’t be guaranteed that the video file names haven’t any blanks.
To build the vlc playlist I use successfully:

```
Dim PL 
PL = Shell("C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC.exe " & certainPath & "\Movie6.flv" & " " & certainPath & "\Movie7.flv" & " " & certainPath & "\Movie8.flv ", 1)
'using "\Movie 6.flv" 'doesn't work of course
'using "\'Movie 6.flv'" 'doesn't work aswell
```

Is there another way to encapsulate file name with blanks?
thankfull for a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that certainPath folder end with \ ( es. "C:\" ), this should work:

```
Dim PL
PL = Shell(chr(34) & "c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe " & chr(34) & chr(34) & certainPath & "Movie 6.flv" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & certainPath & "Movie 7.flv" & chr(34))
```

CHR is a function to returns the character from the ASCII table (the quotes in this case).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, even the chain of titles is concatenate from an array. But I wonder what the difference is between a quote and its representative in ascii.

Comment: Short answer: using the quote or its ascii equivalent is the same thing.
Long answer: Paths containing spaces must always be enclosed in a quote in addition to the standard quote, whether in text or in ASCII.

Comment: oh, I understand. I'll try to replace the ascii equivalent by a double quote from keyboard (only for learning). Thank you very much.